# How to give a delete alert in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to give an alert while delete button is pressed in jQuery. And when i press cancel option also, it is deleting.Can you help me how to give a delete alert in jQuery..
  i am using alert in the following way

```
if(innerHtml == "Delete") {
                    var r=confirm("do you want to delete this record ?");
                    if(r==true){
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
                    nEditing = null;
                    nEditingTable = null;
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: please google atleast to some extent before asking questions here.

Comment: do you want to display an alert before deleting ?

Comment: Yes,I want to add an alert before deleting, and only when the user press ok,delete should happen

Comment: I think following answer(Edwin Alex's) should work, use confirmation msg directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do like this..

```
if(innerHtml == "Delete") {

                    if(confirm("do you want to delete this record ?")){
                      oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
                      nEditing = null;
                      nEditingTable = null;
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: i m sure it wont work when clicking the cancel button in the confirm msg. Pls check your code..

Answer (score 0):

Edwin Alex should be correct.
Make sure you use comfirmation box correctly in your code,

```
if(confirm('do you want to delete this record ?')) {
  alert('deleted');
} else {
  alert('deletion is cancelled');
}
```

if this is not a problem, see whether  `innerHtml` value is "Delete" or not, if its not this code never be excuted